# Clarification on Generic Type Erasure in java code compilation

Tags: java, generics, compilation

**Problem:**
After the parameterized type is compiled and when the class is referenced by a jar, the client is forced to create raw types as the compiler does type erasure.

For Example:

```
public class GenericFeature<T>{
  T object;
  public void dosomething(){
    // do something
  }
}
```

After compiling and adding it as a dependency in another application, the user is not able to use the Parameterized type.

```
GenericFeature<Integer> intFeature = new GenericFeature<Integer>() // is erroring out saying GenericFeature is not parameterized type.
```

**Analysis**
I did read about the type erasure of generics in compilation, as it states that my example parameterized type will be looking as given below after compilation.

```
public class GenericFeature{
  Object object;
  public void dosomething(){
    // do something
  }
}
```

**Quesion:**
If this is how the type erasure happen, then how do the Java's internal objects like `Comparable<T>`, `Class<T>` retain their parameterized constructs.

May be I am missing something very basic, please excuse and educate me in such case.

Comment: this code doesn't compile anyways

Comment: @Sleiman thanks for the catch, i was just typing the code directly when asking the question. and didnt see the typo. Editing it now

Comment: `int` is a keyword and can't be used as a variable name.

Comment: comeon, guys stop finding the typos and help me with the answer..

Answer (score 2):

Take the `<T>` off the class declaration, that is why you cannot use it. This should work:

```
public class GenericFeature<T>{
  T object;
  public void dosomething(){
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: actually it was a typo, I do not have a <T> in the class definition. Its actually `public class GenericFeature<T>` only, just edited the question as well

Comment: With the correction, that could compiles just fine. You still need the <T> at the end of the class name, just not the first <T> you had.

Comment: the code compiles fine, but i have the same problem as i mentioned in the question. That is after the compilation the type erasure happens and the client code is forced to create RAW types instead of Parameterized types

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no problem, with the type erasure. Sorry for misleading, after spending some time analyzing the issue, found out that there is some maven configuration issue in the project where my `GenericFeature<T>` is defined. I am able to retain the type if I move this class to a different project.

Analyzing, more on what was that configuration that created this issue, if i find something then I will post that in my answer.